# javascript element like in jquery? How do I get with the "these" variable

Tags: javascript

this jquery code

```
    $(".entry-content").click(function(){
        console.log(this); // "this" <div class="entry-content"></div>
        alert("aasasd");
    });
```

I tried it myself to reach this parameter when using javascript. I can get it as a parameter from the callback function, but I couldn't get it like this.

```
function $( element ) {
        element = document.querySelectorAll(element);
        this.click = ( callback ) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                element[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    callback( element[i] );
                });
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
    
    $(".entry-content").click(function(element){
        console.log(element); // The "element" is being sent from the callback () function.
        alert("aasasd");
    });
```

So instead, how do I access "this" as in jquery

Comment: and jQuery is openSource....

Comment: @MisterJojo Have you looked at the answers? They are all different, so I can do it in many ways. If I looked at jQuery I would see one It is always better to synthesize multiple ideas and information.

Comment: so what? as you wrote my answer is different from the others and also allows you to have a different approach. where did I wrote that I will forbidden you to read the other answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.bind` when assigning the listener to set a `this` value. With jQuery, `this` is just the element, or `element[i]`.

Since you don't care about the indicies, only the elements, you could also consider iterating over the elements directly:

```js
function $(selector) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return {
    click(callback) {
      for (const element of elements) {
        element.addEventListener('click', callback.bind(element));
      }
    }
  };
}
$(".entry-content").click(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<button class="entry-content">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind this

```js
function $(element) {
  element = document.querySelectorAll(element);
  this.click = (callback) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
      element[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        callback.call(element[i], event);
      });
      // element[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      //   callback.apply(element[i], [event]);
      // });
      // element[i].addEventListener("click", callback.bind(element[i]));
    }
  }
  return this;
}

$(".entry-content").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target); 
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">1</div>
<div class="entry-content">2</div>
<div class="entry-content">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `.bind` to provide element scope

```js
function $(selector) {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];

  return {
    click(callback) {
      elements.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('click', callback.bind(el)));
    },
  };
}

$('.entry-content').click(function () {
  console.log(this); // "this" <div class="entry-content"></div>
  alert('aasasd');
});
```

```html
<button class="entry-content">click</button>
```